# How to find files with no file extension in directory tree with a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

How to write a batch file called `EX5.BAT` that lists all files matching any of the following criteria within the Windows folder and down through its sub directories?

1. Files with an extension starting with letter C.
2. Files without a file extension.

Comment: smells a lot like an assignment. What have you tried? What worked, what did not? Do you have any ideas for how to attack the problem?

Comment: I guess FOR loop could be useful.

Comment: the part a its easy but the second part is dificult litle bit

Comment: @echo off

rem  to enter to C drive

for /r c:\Windows %%x in (*.C*) Do echo %%x

pause

Answer (score 2):

```
dir c:\windows\*. c:\windows\*.c /s/b/a-d
```

Comment: For me this only lists files with no extensions. None the less +1, I completely forget about `dir`.

Comment: There will be no files in the Windows directory with just a c extension, unless you put one there. Try this command (we'll do System32 to make it shorter) `dir %windir%\system32\*. %windir%\system32\*.txt /a-d/b/s`

Comment: ok i try it. its working fine but there a small mistake. so we shold replace  (*.C) with (*.C*) cause we want the extention that start with C like (.COM) ,(.conf) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

#### Individually

```
pushd C:\Windows\
:: Part A
for /r %%a in (*.c*) do Echo %%~a
:: Part B
for /r %%a in (*) do if "%%~xa"=="" Echo %%~a
popd
```

#### In one for-loop

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd C:\Windows\
for /r %%a in (*) do (
set var=%%~xa
if "!var!"=="" Echo %%~a 
if "!var:~0,2!"==".c" Echo %%~a
)
popd
```

The latter method is obviously faster, but I posted the first one in case you wanted to do it individually as it is a lot cleaner.

Comment: you can just put both masks in one for. `... in (*. *.c*)`

Answer (score 0):

I think I fond the Answer:

```
@echo off
rem a)
for /r c:\Windows %%X IN (*.C*) Do Echo %%X 
pause
rem b)
for /r C:\Windows %%x  IN (*.) Do echo %%x
pause
```

Comment: You mean that monacraft gave you