# Windows bat: files without extension (dot in name issue)

Tags: batch-file

At first: it's not a repeated question (I hope). I've searched a lot and found [How to find files with no file extension in directory tree with a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354716/how-to-find-files-with-no-file-extension-in-directory-tree-with-a-batch-file) and [Find and rename files with no extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025410/find-and-rename-files-with-no-extension), among others, but I have a "small" additional problem.

I'm trying to rename multiple (thousands) of jpg files on Windows 10. The name format is "Name (ABC).jpg" or "Multiple Names (ABC).jpg". I need "Some Name.jpg".

**What have you tried?** So many things, none of them a real solution, until this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=)(" %%a in ('dir /b *.jpg') do @rename "%%a(%%b)%%c" "%%a"
for /R %%x in (*.) do ren "%%x" *.png
```

It works fine for most of the files, **except when there's a dot in the name**. If the name is something like "A Name.Supercool (ABC).jpg", it will be only "A Name.Supercool", with no extension.

I know the problem is on (*.), just don't know how to solve...

Comment: "*What have you tried? So many things, none of them a real solution*" - and yet in powershell a real solution is just a `gci *.jpg | ren -newname { ($_.basename -replace '\s+\(.*\)') + ".png"}` away.

Comment: Much better solution, thank you. It could be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that renaming your files to "%%a" produces "A Name.Supercool" - and that this has "no extension".

Ah - but it does. The filename is "A Name" and the extension is ".Supercool"

Were you to rename your file to `"%%a%%c" then the name would become "A Name.Supercool.jpg".

Now why, after attempting to rename your file to extensionless, you are then renaming them to `*.png` I've no idea, and you don't explain, unfortunately. Why wouldn't you simply tack on the `.png` to the `%%a` - if that truly was what you wanted to do?

(BTW - the `for /f ... dir...` approach builds a memory-list of the files, then renames them, so they won't be re-processed as may occur with `for %%x in (*.jpg)...`)

---

Given the terminal-space-in-name problem,

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=)(" %%a in ('dir /b *.jpg') do rename "%%a(%%b)%%c" "%%a%%c"
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "* .jpg"') do (
 SET "name=%%a"
 REN "%%a" "!name:~0,-5!.jpg"
)
endlocal
```

Comment: `"Multiple Names (ABC).jpg"` split on the parens has a space at the end of Names, and if you tack on `.png` then you get `"Multiple Names .png"` with a space in it. I speculate that's why they aren't doing it.

Comment: I tried "%%a(%%b)%%c" "%%a%%c", but it puts a space before the extension, like "A Name .jpg" (edit: better saying, the space stays there). Then I did it (first make it extensionless and then rename). Probably a bad idea for someone who knows what to do...

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to pass `%%a` to a subroutine that removes trailing spaces? Then it can do `ren "%%a(%%b)%%c" "!name!.png"` just once.

Comment: Edition tested. Works with a small flaw: if the name is like "Nice Name! (USA).jpg", the space is not removed.

Comment: Yes - you're likely to get that in batch when the name contains characters that have a special meaning to batch - `%` would no doubt suffer the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Magoo's answer is closer to what I asked, but there is a problem with special characters in file names. TessellatingHeckler posted the best approach as a comment, so here it goes. Batch file:

```
powershell -command "gci *.jpg | ren -newname { ($_.basename -replace '\s+\(.*\)') + '.jpg'};gci *.png | ren -newname { ($_.basename -replace '\s+\(.*\)') + '.png'}"
```

With this I can handle .jpg and .png at once, flawlessly. Thank you all.